# Meaning of "swell not thy cheek"

Tags: meaning, grammar

The passage below is a translation of the Quran:

> And **swell not thy cheek** (for pride)at men,nor walk in insolence through the earth; for Allah loveth not any arrogant boaster.

I want to know the meaning of the bold part. Also, I want to know if the bold part is some kind of figure of speech ? Because I couldn't find anything of it. Also, is swell an archaic and formal word ?
By the way, English is not my first language.

Comment: An interesting question.  Perhaps ask whether the metaphor of "swelling of the cheek" is in the original Arabic, and this translator merely copied it into English... Or whether this metaphor was used by the translator to correspond to something else in the Arabic.  But I think neither of these belongs in this forum.

Comment: You can find 7 translations into English at https://myislam.org/surah-luqman/ayat-18/  - the version you quote is by Abdullah Yusuf Ali and may have been aiming at the idea of puffing out your cheeks - others give different expressions when translating what you should not do with your cheek.

Comment: You could always ask on https://islam.stackexchange.com/ what it actually means. I agree it's not a particularly common English idiom.

Comment: @StuartF thank you. One of the translators of this verse used the phrasal verb " sneer down" which I can't understand it . What exactly they meant by this : " do not sneer down your cheek."

Comment: I think it might refer to how your cheeks puff out when you smile, and people smile when they're proud of themselves.